# C how to ignore lines that starts with * or are spaces only

Tags: c

I am trying to read from a file, line by line and the using strtok to get each word.
But I need to ignore empty lines or lines that starts with * or lines with only spaces.
Here is my code:

```
char line[len];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input)) {
    char* words= strtok(line," ");
         //MY FIRST TRY TO FIND EMPTY LINES
    if(strcmp(line," ") == 0){
        continue;
    }
    int i=0;
    while(words != NULL){
            //MY SECOND TRY TO SKIP EMPTY WORDS
        while(words[i] == ' ' && words[i] != '\0'){
            i++;
        }
        if(words[i] != '\0'){
            fprintf(output,words);
        }
        i=0;
        words=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
 }
```

both tries have failed.

Comment: `if(strcmp(line," ") == 0)` doesn't find an empty line, it finds a line with one space exactly. Perhaps you should show a frament of you input.

Comment: Make your life much easier and eliminate the empty, all spaces and * lines before doing `strtok`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the following code at the beginning of your `while` loop to skip lines beginning with blank characters and then '*' or blank lines:

```
for (i = 0; line[i] && isspace(line[i]); i++)
    ;

if (line[i] == '*' || line[i] == '\0')
    continue;
```

Note: remember to define `i` first and include `<ctype.h>` at the beginning of your source file.